# sql server query outer join where issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables: Post, User and Favorites

```
Post
----------
PostId
Nombre
UserId
Banned

User
----------
UserId
UserName
Info

Favorites
-----------
PostId
UserId
```

I'm trying to get all posts and telling if the posts are favourites or not, so if a post isn't among favourites, it will appear on the query but favourite flag will be false.

this is my query:

```
SELECT
 p.Nombre as title,
 CASE ISNULL(f.PostId,0) WHEN 0 THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END as favorito
 FROM Post p 
 inner join User u on p.UserId = u.UserId 
 left outer join Favorite f on p.PostId = f.PostId 
 where 
 p.Banned = 0
```

and it returns everything, and tells if there is a record in favorites, but when I add the filter on where section

```
 and f.UsuarioId = 4
```

only returns the posts the user likes. Shouldn't be when using left outer join or full outer join that if a record from secondary table doesn't exist should return the records from main table anyways?

¿How can I return all post using filter on secondary table? thanks!

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but since you're joining to User via Post.UserId, it seems like you're only fetching posts made by that user, not posts that they marked as favorites.

If this is the intended behaviour, then Michael's answer is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have filtered on `f.UsuarioId = 4`, that effectively converts the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` by requiring that the `Favorite` have a record of a specific value. To still return all those with no related `Favorite`, you must test for a `NULL` in that table:

```
SELECT
 p.Nombre as title,
 CASE ISNULL(f.PostId,0) WHEN 0 THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END as favorito
FROM
  Post p 
  INNER JOINUser u ON p.UserId = u.UserId 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Favorite f ON p.PostId = f.PostId 
WHERE 
 p.Banned = 0 
 -- Return either those related Favorite records for UsuarioId = 4 or the NULLs
 -- meaning a related record does not exist
 AND (f.UsuarioId = 4 OR f.UsuarioId IS NULL)
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, if I do a second join to favorite,
FROM
  Post p 
  INNER JOINUser u ON p.UserId = u.UserId 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Favorite f ON p.PostId = f.PostId 
  Inner join usuario a on f.usuarioid = a.usuarioId
WHERE 
 p.Banned = 0 
 AND (a.nombre = 'Jhon' or a.nombre is null) why does not work?

Comment: @ArturoSuarez Because it is an `INNER JOIN` between those tables..  `a.nombre` will never be null. You might try `LEFT JOIN usuario a on f.usuarioId = a.usuarioId WHERE p.Banned = 0 AND (a.nombre = 'Jhon' OR f.usuarioId IS NULL)` since `Favorite` is still left joined and will be NULL if no record is present, meaning `a` is also not present.

Comment: You could have also done it in the ON `LEFT OUTER JOIN Favorite f ON p.PostId = f.PostId  AND f.UsuarioId = 4`